# Strange behavior when add element to array by key

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why is array so strange when I add element by key.
For example:

```
var test = new Array();
test['a'] = 'aaa';
test['b'] = 'bbb';

test.length == 0; // true. Why?
```

And when I run:

```
test.map(function(el){
   console.log(el);
});
// nothing print. Why?
```

When I add element with push method everything works OK. Thanks

Comment: [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) `!==` [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: You're using array like it was an object.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays.

Comment: Arrays use numeric keys, for their Arrayness.

Comment: You're adding a property to the object, it doesn't change the length of an array.

Comment: not strange behavior, perfectly correct behavior

Comment: Do: `var test = new Object();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in javascript are not associative, you can't set keys like that i.e.

```
var test = [];

test.push('aaa');
test.push('bbb');

// OR

test[0] = 'aaa';
test[1] = 'bbb';

test.length = 2
```